# Как перевести число bytes в последовательность 0 и 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно преобразовать int в последовательность из 28 символов в формате little-endian, причём предполагается, что каждый байт состоит из 7 бит.

```
Input:
2

Output:
0000010000000000000000000000
```

Я так понимаю, сначала преобразовываем int в bytes.

```
rx = (2).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little')

# b'\x02\x00\x00\x00'
```

А как теперь это преобразовать в строку из 0 и 1 длинной 28 символов, причём чтобы было именно 7 бит в байте?

Comment: А куда Вы хотите деть 8-ые биты каждого байта?

Comment: Я решаю задачу с таким условием, там сказано: "для гипотетической вычислительной системы, где используются байты состоящие только из 7 бит". 8-ые биты здесь идут в следующий байт. Для числа 268435305 ответ должен быть: 1101001111111011111111111111

Comment: *Байт* по определению 8 бит, можете повесить автора задачи. На самом деле правильный термин — *(машинное) слово*.

Comment: @0andriy Не несите ерунды. Определений байта существует несколько, и то, что вам известно только одно, проблема ваша, а не автора задачи. Есть/были системы, где в байте 6, 7, 12 или другое количество бит. Даже сам автор слова "byte" использовал его для 6 битных единиц информации. Так что повесьтесь лучше сами.

Answer (score 1):

В итоге это решается без использования bytes.

```
n = int(input())
n = bin(n)[2:]
addition = "0" * (28-len(n))
n = addition + n
for i in range(21, -1, -7):
    print(i)
    print(n[i:i+7], end = "")
```